# Access VBA Userfrom opens with combobox getting focused with tab stop turned off

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, focus, tabstop

When opening my User from the sub form, which is a data sheet/ record source, has a combo box in each row and it is getting focused, even though I have the tab stop property turned off.
The main problem is that the combo box is on the righten side and therefore the form appears as scrolled to the right instead of starting at the the beginning.

I have turned off the tab stop property but it still happens.

I want the first column in the sub form to be visible and not have the user form scrolled to the right by default when opening the form, i.e. not have the combo box focused.

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue. There must be a reason combobox gets focus, such as code.

Comment: I have checked all the code and there is no event that sets focus to said combo box. Since it is work related I cannot upload my code/ file either :/

Comment: Set the tab order of the controls on your form, make the leftmost control the first.

Comment: Even when combobox set with TabIndex of 0, I cannot replicate this issue. When form opens as Datasheet, focus is on leftmost column regardless of which control has TabIndex  0.

Comment: Sorry my bad. The subview is not a datasheet but rather a Continuous Form , whose recordsource is a table. The columns are not selectable/ editable. So the only thing in the subview able to be tabbed to/ selected is this combobox